# Number and label equations in aligned environment (cannot switch to align)

Tags: equations, numbering

I have the following

```
\begin{equation*}
A=\left\{
B|~\qquad \begin{aligned}
&C\\
&D\\
&E
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

And I would like to number and label only the line corresponding to "E". How can I do this?

Comment: `equation*` does not use numbering. You can use `\tag{E}` in an `equation*` but not inside `aligned`, as far as I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

with `empheq` package is simple:

```
\begin{empheq}[left={A=\empheqlbrace}, right=\empheqrbrace]{align}
    &\quad  C   \notag  \\  
B|  &\quad  D   \notag  \\
    &\quad  E   \label{eq:important}
\end{empheq}
```

**Addendum:**
with some trick can be also done demand to have equation number inside of equation ...

[image]

```
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:important}
\begin{empheq}[left={A=\empheqlbrace}, right=\empheqrbrace]{align}\label{eq:important}
    &\qquad C   \notag  \\  
B|  &\qquad D   \notag  \\
    &\qquad E   \quad   \eqref{eq:important}\notag
\end{empheq}
```

Comment: Thank you. Though, I would like the equation number (1) to appear right next to "E", so between "E" and the right big "{". Any hint about that?

Comment: @Luca, here is habit that you yours thankfulness express with voting and and accepting the answer, which solve your problem on the best way :)